# Laravel Homestead Up Error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have an error every time i run homestead up from my console
can someone please give me a solution to this?

```
    homestead.bat up
    C:/Users/Evan Oscar/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:17:in `read': No such file or directory - C:/cygwin64/home/Evan Oscar/.homestead/Homestead.yaml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Users/Evan Oscar/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in `new'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:673:in `unload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

this is my homestead.yaml file:

```
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 1
    provider: virtualbox

    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    folders:
    - map: ~/Code
    to: /home/vagrant/Code

    sites:
    - map: homestead.app
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

    databases:
    - homestead

    variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
    value: local
```

I suspect that my folder name could be a problem?
since i use "Evan Oscar" or maybe there's something that i miss when i installed homestead?
Can someone help me with this please?
I have search the web for the solution but none have really worked

Comment: I also have accidentally deleted the homestead.yaml file. But i copy pasted it from the file that have been downloaded manually

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the steps from the beginning so you can check if you did something wrong. I suggest you delete your homestead folder and try installing it again to see what happens.

Did you installed homestead locally or globally?

( like `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead` or  `composer global require laravel/homestead` )

If the answer is locally you need to go inside the folder created when you cloned homestead and then run this command to init the config files of homestead ( ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml or c:\users\username.homestead\Homestead.yaml for windows)

```
bash init.sh
```

If you installed it globally you can use this command from anywhere. After that you just need to configure the Homestead.yaml file as explained in the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).

Don't forget to create your

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
```

I noticed you are using the default style for homestead.yaml config, try changing the urls for a more windows-like format

```
authorize: c:\Users\username\.ssh\homestead_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:\Users\username\.ssh\homestead_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\
```

Only then you run

```
homestead up
```